# How can I browse the hard disk attached to my Airport Extreme from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, finder, hard-drive, airport

I have a gen 5 AEBS which has a total of 3 HFS+ partitions across 2 USB hard drives (USB hub in the middle).

On my Macbook Pro Retina, I can see all 3 HFS+ partition in the Finder. Finder shows the AEBS on the left side (under "shared) and clicking on the AEBS in Finder shows me all the 3 HFS+ partitions "on" the AEBS.

In a similar manner, I want to access the AEBS USB hard drives from my iPhone 5 but I couldn't find an app for that. Does anyone know of an app or in-built way for me to access the drives attached to my AEBS? I'm looking for access when I'm on the AEBS WiFi but if I can also access it from the internet, that'll be a nice bonus!

Comment: What sharing protocol are you using? I believe the AirPort Extreme supports more than one. If its AFP (likely the default), there is an iPhone app called ezShare that can browse files. Once you get it sorking locally, doing it over the Internet is just a matter of opening the right ports on your router.

Answer (score 1):

Try FileExplorer Free from the AppStore.  I got my iPhone to see the files on a HD attached to my Airport Extreme Router.

The HD has to be formatted as HFS+ (Mac OS Extended Journaled)